# Laravel: selecting multiple values with radio button

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to create a radio button field that will be selecting **present, late, absent, others** for each row of student.

The problem is... When i click the radio button for another student row... the radio button will pass down on the currently selected row and the one i selected previously will be gone.

Please Help.

**Here's my view**

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
   <th>Student ID</th>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Present</th>
    <th>Late</th>
    <th>Absent</th>
    <th>Others</th>
    <th>Comments</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($users as $users)
            <tr>
      <td>{{ $users->student_id  }} </td>
       <td>{{ $users->student_firstname  }} {{ $users->student_lastname  }}</td> 
     <td>{{ Form::radio('result', 'present', true)}}</td>
    <td> {{ Form::radio('result', 'late' ) }}</td>
   <td>{{ Form::radio('result', 'absent') }}</td>
    <td>{{ Form::radio('result', 'others') }}</td>
    <td>  <input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" class="form-control"></td>





          @endforeach

            </tr>
```

Comment: Did you try: `{{ Form::radio('result['.$student->id.']', 'late' ) }}` ?

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I haven't tried that yet hahahah thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all input fields have the exact same name of `results` its treated as one big input group with only one correct answer.

By appending the student id `'result['.$student->id.']'` you are separating each row of input buttons into their own groups, allowing multiple radio button subgroups within a single `<form>`.

Which you can then catch the array of answers for each subgroup with Input::get('results') or $request->get('results') if your using Laravel's Form Request Validation.

Comment: wait... so if I input  Input::get('results') in my controller this will get all the results of each student(e.g. present, absent, late)  with different student id?

Comment: Yes you'll have an associtive array of student_id=>result.